# PDF, HTML and SVG conversions are not working in Aspose.Cells

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, aspose-cells

I have a .NET Core 2.0 project and use Aspose.Cells version 18.2.0. When I try to convert valid XLS to PDF, HTML or SVG, it fails.

I'm using this code:

```
Workbook doc = new Workbook(inputStream); // my input file stream
doc.Save(outputStream, SaveFormat.Pdf);
```

Instead of `SaveFormat.Pdf` you can try Svg and Html

As result of PDF conversion I get PDF file with "Invalid file structure", as Pdf Readers say.

As result of SVG conversion I get SVG file that any browser is unable to open.

As result of HTML conversion I get Html file that contains just a lot of random symbols.

I've noticed that this issue appears only in .NET Core project, and in .NET Framework 4.6.1 everything works fine. CSV and TXT conversions are fine on both Core and Framework.

So my question is: Is there any workaround to get it working on .NET Core or only option is to use .NET Framework until it gets fixed? Or maybe I missed something in docs?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Cells/ it looks that it doesn't even support .NET Core/.NET Standard. What did you expect would happen? Did you run .NET Core Portability Analyzer on the assembly to check the compatibility?

Comment: @Tseng It supports .Net Core from version 18.2.0, i first installed it when it was 18.1.0 and got warning in VS that this version was build for .Net framework, but after update it has gone. I'm able to use it, but certain formats fail

Comment: At least the package doesn't contain the metadata which tells which platforms it supports. Packages made for multiple platforms look like this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/ (look the dependency section, it lists .NET Standard 1.0, 1.3, 2.0, .NET Framework 4.x etc.) so I wouldn't be purely sure unless you run [.NET Portability Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) on it

Comment: Ok, I'll try it, thanks

Comment: We have requested the product team of Aspose.Cells for .NET Core to shed some light on this issue. Once, there is some news for you, we will update you asap. ------ Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: Please check the Update-2 in my reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Update-3**

Aspose.Cells for 18.4 and onward supports all the features in .NET Core/Standard as it supports in .NET 2.0/4.0. Please check the updated article from the following link.

https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Feature+Overview

---

**Update-2**

Please download and try the Aspose.Cells for .NET - **April Release i.e. 18.4** from the following link and it should fix most of your issues.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Cells/18.4.0

Let us know if you find any issue, we will look into it and help you asap.

---

**Update-1**

We are afraid, these features are not supported at the moment but we will support them in future as soon as possible.

Please see the [Feature Overview](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Feature+Overview) page on Aspose.Cells for .NET documentation for more help.

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose